# C# How to make another button appear by clicking a different button?

Tags: c#, click, appearance

I want to click on a button and make a text block and another button appear. I managed to make the text block appear. How do I make the button appear. I can't seem to find a function that does so. Also, does it need to be a different private void statement. So far I have:

```
private void one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    oneBlock.Text = "one";
}

private void one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    one_Trans.ClickMode = "two";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thank you man. this is exactly what i was looking for. I knew there had to be some kind of visibility property. Do u recommend using the visibility property for the text block as well or is what I've done fine?

Comment: No problem. It's up to you to decide. It seems what you did was assign the textblock text when the button was clicked. Textblocks also have a Visibility property so you could implement it the same way as the button.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible=true;
}
```

on the click event of button1

Answer (score 0):

Put everything into the same event

```
private void one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   oneBlock.Text = "one";
   one_Trans.ClickMode = "two";
   button1.Visible = true;
}
```